# Laravel 4 model without eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm just starting to learn about Laravel and trying to migrate from CI. I have a few simple questions.

1. Do I have to use eloquent when using a model?
2. In CI using model you just extends Model. Is there the same to use in Laravel? So far all the docs I found only state that I have to use eloquent if I want to use model. Eloquent is a bit confusing at the moment for me. So I just want to use simple query builder in my model.

I guess number 1 and 2 questions are somehow related.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fluent:

```
DB::table("...");
```

Eloquent, which is based on PDO is ORM and more abstracted from raw queries.

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent is a great tool, so I recommend familiarizing yourself with it if you get the chance.

You can build queries on your own using Laravel's query builder.

Read up on it here, I hope this answers your question and sorry if I misunderstood!

http://laravel.com/docs/queries

Good luck!

Comment: I know eloquent is great. I'm trying to get used to it. But like I said, can I apply it without eloquent for models? Can I put the query builder inside a model and call that model from controller? Like CI?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can`t create a model without extends `eloquent` like [laravel 4 Doc](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent)

```
class User extends Eloquent {}
```

**because** a model in laravel based into `eloquent ORM` unlike `CodeIgniter`

**If**  you need to deal with database tables with creating models ,you can use `DB` class 
like [laravel 4 Doc](http://laravel.com/docs/databas)

`DB::select('')` and  `DB::table('')`